# How to fill and access a Django ArrayField?

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql

To solve my (kinda specific) problem, I found that I have to use Django ArrayField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

I have defined it in my `models.py` file as

```
Bla = ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(),
        size=4
        null=True
        )
```

But **how do I actually put information inside?** Ideally both a whole python list, as also at a single place.

And once it is in there, **how can I retrieve it?** Both on python side, as also in the `.html` file?

PS: I don't think that the whole background of the problem is relevant, so I omitted it for now, but I will of course provide all necessary details if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 10):

You just assign a list of integers.

```
class M(models.Model):
    bla = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), size=4, null=True)

m = M.objects.create(bla=[1, 3, 3, 7])

# (or, equivalently,)

m = M()
m.bla = [1, 3, 3, 7]
m.save()

# (or, equivalently,)

m = M(bla=[1, 3, 3, 7])
m.save()
```

Reading `m.bla`, you get back a list of integers, which you can access in Python or Django templates like any other list.

See also [the documentation on the various extra lookups for ArrayFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield).

Comment: Whoah, thanks! I got a new error message, so thats progress! "Manager isn't accessible via Group instances"
And (really no offense meant :D) did you really just put in the answer the same link as I put in the question? :D But I promise to look at it again, maybe I will understand it now. I really had no idea, that I had to go through that whole .objects.create() hassle, because for all my other fields I don't have to. I guess thats some built in magic ^^

Comment: No, you don't have to go through `.objects.create` -- it's just a shorthand for doing `m = M(bla=...); m.save();`. And it's not exactly the same link, it's the next section about those lookups. But let me amend my answer a little.

Comment: It's a bit strange this isn't spelled out in the docs.